# Creating a grid of buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I can not figure out how to make a grid of the received buttons
I tried to do it with grid but it gives an error

`_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`

I can't figure out how to implement it.
As I understand it, he swears at the fact that he already uses pack on the buttons. How else?

```
import random as rn
import tkinter as tk
def main_fun():
    m = []
    min = int(ent1.get())
    max = int(ent2.get())
    cel = int(ent3.get())
    while cel > 0:
        count = rn.randint(min,max)
        cel -= count
        if cel >= 0:
            m.append(count)
        else:
            m.append(count - (cel + count))
    button_count = len(m)
    for i in range(button_count):
        button = tk.Button(win, text=str(m[i]))
        button.grid(row=i+1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
win = tk.Tk()
btn1 = tk.Button(win, text="Create", command= main_fun)
btn1.pack()
ent1 = tk.Entry(win)
ent1.pack()
ent2 = tk.Entry(win)
ent2.pack()
ent3 = tk.Entry(win)
ent3.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You either need to use `.grid()` for everything in the same container - or moved the `.pack()`ed items into a separate Frame, in which case it doesn't matter that they use a different geometry manager.

Comment: The error is right, of course.  You have 4 buttons managed with pack.  The solution is to create a separate Frame to contain your grid of buttons.  The Frame is placed with `pack`, but its guts are manged with `grid`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed everything to grid. But how now to make this grid beautiful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your button in a frame instead of on the root window:

```
for i in range(button_count):
        frame = tk.Frame(win)
        button = tk.Button(frame, text=str(m[i]))
        button.grid(row=i+1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        frame.pack()
```

You cannot use multiple geometry managers (`.pack()`, `.place()`, or `.grid()`) in the same frame/window, which means that in order to use `grid()` on a widget alongside `pack()`, it needs to be in a separate frame from the widgets you are displaying with `pack()`.  Then, once you've used `grid()` on the widgets you want in the separate frame, you can then use `frame.pack()` to place the frame inside the root window with the rest of your widgets.

Alternatively, if you don't need to use `grid()`, just use `pack()` on the button :)

```
for i in range(button_count):
        button = tk.Button(win, text=str(m[i]))
        button.pack()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that? @toyotaSupra